# How to resolve 'certifcate verify failed' error on vagrant box built using Puphpet

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, puphpet, vagrant-windows

I built a Ubuntu (14.04) box using [Puphpet](https://puphpet.com/).

When I run the command `vagrant up`. The box does get generated but the provisioning is interrupted by the following error:

> ==> default: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'deep_merge' (>= 0), here is why :
>   ==> default:           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_ connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error:
>   certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
>   ==> default: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activesupport' (>= 0), here is why:
>   ==> default:           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_ connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error:
>   certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
>   ==> default: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'vine' (>= 0), here is why:
>   ==> default:           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_ connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error:
>   certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
>   The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes
>   that this means the command failed. The output for this command should
>   be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went
>   wrong.

I am using Vagrant 1,8.1. The relevant [Vagrantfile](http://pastebin.com/fTcGV9jR) and [config.yaml](http://pastebin.com/RsXqjABV) file. I am working on a Windows 7 host machine.

Appreciate any help in the matter.

Comment: This might help - https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Answer (score 0):

Melekes' answer is probably on the right path. There was an SSL upgrade in RubyGems which caused quite a few headaches in other tools using Ruby. You can manually upgrade the RubyGems gem itself using something like `gem install rubygems` to upgrade, or follow the directions at the Ruby site to manually fix this if the automatic upgrade doesn't work.

http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue